# Is it safe to connect PC USB ground to 12V DC ground?

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, pc

I want to drive a stepper motor (Nema 17), for which I have chosen 12V power supply (switching). In order to develop/play, I would like to connect a devboard (something akin Arduino) to USB. However, I cannot drive the motor from USB or from the devboard, so I will need my 12V power supply.

Can I just connect the grounds of PC USB with the power supply ground? They are both connected to the same power outlet. I'm afraid of damaging my PC power supply, or other internal components.

After development, both arduino and stepper motor will use the switching supply, with extra 5V voltage regulator for arduino, which I think I dont need when using USB.

EDIT: the 12 DC power supply is not grounded.

[image]

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: Which 12V Switching supply?  The vast majority shouldn't have an issue with this, but it would be great if you could click the edit link below your question and add more info about the 12V supply.

Comment: It depends on the 12V power supply. PC power supply is earthed. If the 12V power supply is earthed too, and the 12V supply return wire disconnects, all the return current will flow via the tiny USB cable return wire.

Comment: Oh, you are right. The switching power supply is not grounded! :(. It's DSP6012C but I haven't found an English site with the info for it.

Comment: @FilipSivák having non-earthed mains input can also be a bad thing. The output may capacitively float at voltages that can make it unsafe to hot-plug something to an earthed computer for example.